# Unable to plot vector field using quiver in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, ode

I am quite new to Matlab so I apologize if I am making some obvious mistakes, but I have a second order ordinary differential equation that I am trying to plot the vector field of. I have looked at various resources on this site, the MATLAB documentation and MATLAB forums but I am still having trouble.

I have tried solving the ODE with the `ode45` function, this gives my a single solution that I can plot. I am using the function `odeToVectorField` to transform my ODE into a system of first order ODE. I have a feeling this is what is preventing me from properly doing what I want because it give me a set of symbolic equations that I am difficulty to evaluate over the meshgrid.

Here is my code so far:

```
% Setup outside variables
clear
mu = 0.75;  % resistance variable
l = 1;      % length of pendulum
g = 9.81;   % gravity

% Next we setup the domains of the vector space.
xdom = linspace(-pi,pi,51); % define the X axis space
ydom = linspace(-pi,pi,51); % define the Y axis space
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xdom,ydom);    % create a meshgrid for the vector field

% Define the system of ODEs
syms y(t)
eqn = diff(y,t,2) == - mu.*diff(y,t,1) - (g/l).*sin(diff(y,t,0));
U = odeToVectorField(eqn) % this is the part where I think I am doing wrong

Uf = matlabFunction(U(1), 'vars',{'t','Y'})  % trying to set a function handle for the first ODE
Vf = matlabFunction(U(2), 'vars',{'t','Y'})  % trying to set a function handle for the second ODE

% Now we plot it
figure
quiver(X,Y,Uf(X,Y), Vf(X,Y))
```

Here is a screenshot of my output. I have purposefully left out some semi colons to help you visualize what I am trying to do.

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `Uf=Y(2)`, it will always just return a single number. a 1x1 matrix. And as the error says, it needs to be the same size as X

Comment: I don't know much about it, but I think you are wrong. The output is not a vector field to plot  with quiver. If you check the `odeToVectorField` docs, there is a demo on how to use it together with `matlabFunction` and plot. `odeToVectorField` is supposed to "Reduce order of differential equations to first-order", not generate a vector field!

Comment: Thank you @AnderBiguri for your comments. How should I then access each component of the system of first order ODEs? I managed to get the result I wanted by changing the way I declare my ODE ```U = Y;``` and ```V = - mu.*Y - (g/l).*sin(X);``` Is it possible to get Matlab to generate these equations for me using odeToVectorField?